# Unable to get values from switch statement to push in to an array

Tags: javascript

I've spent hours trying to figure out this exercise and stuck at this point.  I'm unable to get values from my switch statement to push to an array for "displayVal", and "val" variables.

```
const getDeck = () => {
  const suits = ['Spades','Hearts','Diamonds','Clubs'];
  let cards = [];

  for(let s=0; s < suits.length; s++){

   for(let d = 0; d < 13; d++){
    let displayVal;
    let val;

     switch (d) {
      case (d === 1):
        displayVal = "Ace";
        val = 11;
        break;
      case (d >=2 && d <= 10):
         displayVal = d;
         val = d;
         break;
        case (d === 11):
          displayVal = "Jack"
          val = 10;
          break;
        case (d === 12):
          displayVal = "Queen"
          val = 10;
          break;
        case (d === 13):
          displayVal = "King"
          val = 10;
     }
    cards.push({
    val,
    displayVal,
    suit: suits[s]
  } ); 

   }

 }
 return cards;
}

const deck = getDeck();
console.log(`Deck length equals 52? ${deck.length === 52}`);
```

Comment: the cases in switch statment must take a value. you are passing conditionis

Comment: Either use values, as suggested by @cmgchess - OR - replace: `switch (d)` with `switch true` and you may use the conditions as-is (such as `d === 1`, `d >= 2 && d <= 10`, `d === 11`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

***Using Branch if-else***

Actually, you are using conditions so go ahead with branched if-else

```
const getDeck = () => {
      const suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"];
      let cards = [];
    
      for (let s = 0; s < suits.length; s++) {
        for (let d = 0; d < 13; d++) {
          let displayVal;
          let val;
    
          if (d === 1) {
            displayVal = "Ace";
            val = 11;
          } else if (d >= 2 && d <= 10) {
            displayVal = d;
            val = d;
          } else if (d === 11) {
            displayVal = "Jack";
            val = 10;
          } else if (d === 12) {
            displayVal = "Queen";
            val = 10;
          } else if (d === 13) {
            displayVal = "King";
            val = 10;
          } else {
            displayVal = "";
            val = 0;
          }
          cards.push({
            val,
            displayVal,
            suit: suits[s],
          });
        }
      }
      return cards;
    };
    
    const deck = getDeck();
    console.log(deck);
    console.log(`Deck length equals 52? ${deck.length === 52}`);
```

***Using Switch case***

```
const getDeck = () => {
    const suits = ['Spades','Hearts','Diamonds','Clubs'];
    let cards = [];
  
    for(let s=0; s < suits.length; s++){
  
     for(let d = 0; d < 13; d++){
      let displayVal;
      let val;
  
       switch (true) {
        case (d === 1):
          displayVal = "Ace";
          val = 11;
          break;
        case (d >=2 && d <= 10):
           displayVal = d;
           val = d;
           break;
          case (d === 11):
            displayVal = "Jack"
            val = 10;
            break;
          case (d === 12):
            displayVal = "Queen"
            val = 10;
            break;
          case (d === 13):
            displayVal = "King"
            val = 10;
          default:
            displayVal =""
            val =0
       }
      cards.push({
      val,
      displayVal,
      suit: suits[s]
    } ); 
  
     }
  
   }
   return cards;
  }
  
  const deck = getDeck();
  console.log(deck);
  console.log(`Deck length equals 52? ${deck.length === 52}`);
```

Comment: hello (vanakkam) bro. In the code, inner-for loop it says `for (let d = 0; d < 13; d++)`. This means `d` will iterate from `0` till `12` only (`d < 13`). But, in the `else if` we observe: `else if (d === 13)`. Same is in `switch case` also - but that mistake is copy-pasted from the question, I guess.

Comment: vanakkam bro, yeah you are right, he asked about  "Unable to get values from switch statement to push into an array" so he did a mistake in the switch case so I point out what he did that solve bro.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way / approach that may be used here.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const getDeck = () => {
  const suits = ['Spades','Hearts','Diamonds','Clubs'];
  const getValueOf = x => x === 1 ? 11 : x > 10 ? 10 : x;
  const displayValMap = {1: 'Ace', 11: 'Jack', 12: 'Queen', 13: 'King'};
  return suits.map(
    suit => (
      [
        ...Array(13)
        .keys()
      ]
      .map(x => x + 1)
      .map(d => ({
        val: getValueOf(d),
        displayVal: d in displayValMap
          ? displayValMap[d]
          : d,
        suit
      }))
    )
  ).flat();
}

const deck = getDeck();
console.log(`Deck length equals 52? ${deck.length === 52}`);
console.log(deck);
```

**Explanation**

- Set-up ways to get `val` and `displayVal` (in above snippet, `getValueOf` - a one-line method; and `displayValMap` an object, is used)
- Iterate through the `suits`
- Use `...` spread-operator to generate an array of length 13, then get the keys of the array.
- Use `.map` to make the generated array start from 1, instead of 0
- For each element in the array, create an object with `val`, `displayVal` and `suit` props
- And, finally, use `.flat()` to return all objects into a single array instead of nested-arrays.

---

Another way may be:

```js
const getDeck = () => ['Spades','Hearts','Diamonds','Clubs'].map(
    suit => (
      [
        ...Array(13)
        .keys()
      ]
      .map(d => ({
        val: (d === 0 ? 10 : d > 9 ? 9 : d) + 1,
        displayVal: {0: 'Ace', 10: 'Jack', 11: 'Queen', 12: 'King'}[d] || d + 1,
        suit
      }))
    )
).flat();

console.log(getDeck().length);
console.log(getDeck());
```